# Writing csv without csv module

Tags: python, list, function, csv, dictionary

Below is a line of code using the csv module but my goal is to try to implement the same code without the use of that module or pandas package while maintaining the same output. The csv file I am using is : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PnQzoefx-IiB3D5BKVOrcawoVFLIPVXQ/view?usp=sharing

And below is the code I currently have in Python :

```
    def parse_planets_file(fname) : 

        import csv

        with open(fname) as inputfile : 
            reader = csv.reader(inputfile)
            inputm = list(reader)

            method = inputm.pop(0)
            del method[0]
            data = {}
            for row in inputm:
                if row[0] not in data:
                    data[row[0]] = {h:[] for h in method}

                for s, a in enumerate(method):
                    data[row[0]][a].append(float(row[s+1]) if row[s+1] else row[s+1])
            return data

fname = "exoplanets.csv"
print(parse_planets_file(fname))
```

Also, my output contains whitespace in the form of ' ' which I would like to skip, how would I go about that? Thanks!

Comment: "without the use of that module or pandas package"—why? `csv` especially, as that's in the standard library.

Comment: it is a requirement for an assignment I am currently working on and I can't get around it without bringing up errors

Comment: Your code does nothing except defining a function. More this function doesn't write anything.

Comment: Fixed it, the problem still stands I want to implement the code without the use of csv module

Comment: To read all lines in a file, you want to use `input_file.readlines()` which returns a list (one element per line). To write a `.csv` file, you just need to create the file `with open("exoplanets.csv", "w") as output_file:` and do things like `output_file.write("a; b; c\n")`. I let your build (a, b, c) from your input file. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to parse a conventionally-formatted CSV (like what is linked in the description)

```
list_of_dicts = {}
with open('exoplanets.csv','r') as file_handle:
    file_content = file_handle.read()
for line_index, line in enumerate(file_content.split('\n')):
    if line_index==0: # header
        headers = line.split(',')
    else:
        my_data = {}
        column_entries_in_this_line = line.split(',')
        for col_index, entry in enumerate(column_entries_in_this_line):
            my_data[headers[col_index]] = entry
        list_of_dicts.append(my_data)
```